# Getting KeyError: 'val_acc' while train my dataset with images

Tags: python, keras, image-recognition

I am trying to train data-set with images with the following code but, I am getting:

> KeyError: 'val_acc'

```py
#Directory in which to create models
save_direc = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'idenprof_models')

# Name of model files
model_name = 'idenprof_weight_model.{epoch:03d}-{val_acc}.h5'

# Create Directory if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.isdir(save_direc):
    os.makedirs(save_direc)
# Join the directory with the model file
modelpath = os.path.join(save_direc, model_name)

# Checkpoint to save best model
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=modelpath,
                             monitor='val_acc',
                             verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             save_weights_only=True,
                             period=1)
```

Comment: Did you provide validation data, and does your model have the accuracy metric?

Comment: can you give me that code?

for the validation data...

Comment: No, just giving away random code would not answer the question, if we don't know what the problem is. You didn't answer my question either.

Answer (score 0):

> change from val_acc to val_accuracy

```
# Name of model files
model_name = 'idenprof_weight_model.{epoch:03d}-{val_accuracy}.h5'


# Checkpoint to save best model
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=modelpath,
                             monitor='val_accuracy',
                             verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True,
                             save_weights_only=True,
                             period=1)
```